# How to -editColumn:row:withEvent:select: with NSView-based table view using core data

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I'm in Cocoa programming 4th ed. chapter 9 challenge.
I can not get the editColumn:row:withEvent:select to kick in. Calls to other tableView instance methods work. 
This method is in the tableViewController and not the myDocumentController.
If this method is located within the myDocumentController it will work. What I do not like about adding it to the myDocumentController is the extra code needed to get it to work.

The method editColumn:row:withEvent:select gets processed since the table view scrolls to the row. The rest of the method does not work.

The documentation says: ../this method attempts to make the view at the specified column and row the first responder, which will begin editing if the view supports editing./..

First off how does one make the `NSTableCellView` **First Responder**?
Then how does one make sure the `NSTableCellView` is editable?

What I have seen is references to `[[tableView window] setInitialFirstResponder:[tableView self]]; and [[tableView window] makeFirstResponder:[tableView self]];`. These do not make the cell's object first responder.

```
BOOL editingEnded = [[tableView window] makeFirstResponder:[tableView self]];

if (editingEnded)
{
    NSLog(@"End current edits sucessfull.");
}
else if(!editingEnded)  {
    NSLog(@"Unable to end editing.");
    return;
}


// Select a row. There is no logic here yet. 
NSUInteger row = 10;
[tableView editColumn:0
                  row:row   // Row is scrolled into view but stays disabled. 
            withEvent:nil
               select:YES];
```

Comment: IBOutlets should be within the class that is the file's owner of the NIB which instantiates the object you want a pointer to.  If carArrayController is not the owner of the NIB with the tableView, you need to set that NSTableView* pointer in your own code-- the NIB loading process will not do it for you, and there should be a visual indication in XCode that the outlet is unconnected.

Comment: You're certain that tableView's not nil for all of this?  What makes you certain the selection of row index 1 is working?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of view are you using for the table cell view? With view-based tables, `-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` attempts to set the cell view as the first responder. If the cell view doesn't accept first responder, then it won't work.

You can make the cell view accept first responder, if that makes sense for the type of view that it is.

Or, you can select the row and then use `-[NSWindow makeFirstResponder:]` to make one of the cell view's subviews the first responder. For a text field or text view, that will effectively initiate editing. If the cell view is an `NSTableCellView`, then you probably want to make its `textField` the first responder. You would obtain the cell view itself using `-[NSTableView viewAtColumn:row:makeIfNecessary:]`.

---

Update:

In the comments below, you described your cell view as an "Image & Text Table Cell View" which I take it means the set of views by that name in IB: an `NSTableCellView` with `NSTextField` and `NSImageView` subviews connected to its outlets. Since your cell view (the `NSTableCellView`) is not itself editable, you can't use `--editColumn:row:withEvent:select:`. Instead, you have to make one of its subviews (the text field, in this case) the first responder. You have to do this explicitly. So, you need to use the code I put in my comment of July 31st:

```
[window makeFirstResponder:[[tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:NO] textField]];
```

That is, you obtain the cell view; from that you obtain the text field; then you ask the window to make that text field the first responder.

Given that you also want the row to be selected, you need to do that separately:

```
[tableView selectRowIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:row] byExtendingSelection:NO];
```

If there's any chance that the window itself is not the key window, then you need to make it the key window:

```
[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
```

Comment: I'm using NSView-Based. I added `[[tableView window] makeFirstResponder:[tableView window]];` and it allowed `[tableView editColumn:0 row:row withEvent:nil select:YES];` to work. What I don't understand is that you say to make "Table Cell View" accept "first responder" status  but I made the `[tableView window]` "first responder" not the "Table Cell View"? Could you explain?

Comment: I just tried the code from the supplied examples from the book and it did not work. I can't figure out why? I can't wait to become a seasoned cocoa programmer.`                  NSWindow *w = [tableView window];
    [w makeFirstResponder:w];` ?

Comment: I found a possible answer. You make the window "first responder"if window does not understand the message, the message gets passed up in the responder chain, until a parent element or grandparent (and so on) UI control element understands the message. Otherwise it will be ignored. I s this corect

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps `-editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` was working all along but your window did not have key status. You may just need to do `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]`.

Comment: I would not expect making the window its own first responder to help. That would typically *stop* editing because it would make whatever text field or text view in the table no longer the first responder.

Comment: So your saying that my window should already be first responder.  How do I test for this? This code says it does. `NSWindow *w = [tableView window]; [w makeFirstResponder:w]; BOOL editingEnded = [w makeFirstResponder:w]; if (editingEnded)` I'v been on this for the past two days.

Comment: No. The first responder is a property of a window. That is, a window *has* a first responder within it. If you make the window its own first responder then no other view within it is the first responder and so no text field or text view will be actively editing. (If you make the window its own first responder and then set some other view within it to be its first responder, then the first step was just wasted.) In order for a a text field within a window to be editing, it has to be the window's first responder **and** the window has to be the key window (`-makeKeyAndOrderFront:`).

Comment: From the Docs: `Note: When using NSView-based table views, this method attempts to make the view at the specified column and row the first responder, which will begin editing if the view supports editing.` how do you enable editing? I might be repeating the question and you might be repeating the answer but I don't see the connection.

Comment: There is the `window first responder` then we mention `first responder` in `editColumn:row:withEvent:select:` Are we talking about the same `first responder`

Comment: Have you tried `[window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil]` just before calling `-editColumn:...`?

Comment: Yes I have. I have added the code in the main post. please take a look at it.  If you need all the code let me know.

Comment: OK, so I ask again: what kind of view are you using for your cell view? An `NSTableCellView` or subclass? Just a bare `NSTextField`? Something else? If an `NSTableCellView`, is its `textField` outlet connected to a text field? Have you tried the equivalent of `[window makeFirstResponder:[[tableView viewAtColumn:0 row:row makeIfNecessary:NO] textField]]`?

Comment: It's an `Image & Text Table Cell View` which is an `NSImageView and NSTextField'. Manually selecting the Text cell to edit it works.

Comment: "Manually" by clicking on it with the mouse? Or did you mean my recent code suggestion to programmatically make the text field the first responder? That is, is your original question answered?

Comment: Was away for a couple of days. Yes programmatically. Mouse clicks work perfectly, the field becomes editable.

Comment: Take a look at the main post I rewrote the question and think I have nailed it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a summary of what I've said in the comments above.